# When I create pie chart with SVG, browsers render incorrectly

Tags: web, svg, charts

I want to create pie chart with SVG in WEB, but faced with problem in rendering.
For example: http://jsfiddle.net/shranet/dhvqo9z2/4/

I tested on Safari 8.0.8 (Mac) and Chrome 43 (Windows).

Result:
http://s8.postimg.org/gme22ea6t/render_problem.png

When I set attribute value of path to "M 50 50 L 50 0 A 50,50 0 `0`,1 `100 50` z" or "M 50 50 L 50 0 A 50,50 0 `1`,1 `0 50` z", all worked perfectly.

Why?

Comment: When I follow the [arc implementation notes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcImplementationNotes) I don't get 50, 50 for the centre of the elliptical arc. I suggest the implementations are correct and your calculations/expectations are in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final point of your arc segment (9.14 21.32) is not on the circumference of the circle.

If we calculate it's distance from the centre of the circle:

```
sqrt( (50 - 9.14)^2 + (50-21.32)^2 ) = 49.92
```

That's far enough from the radius of 50 to throw everything off.

The other issue is that you are trying to create arcs that are over 270 degrees.  You get numerical accuracy issues when you try to do that.  For something like your graph, where you need greater accuracy, I would recommend you keep your arcs to a max of 90 degrees.

If we update your example to fix these two things, you get much better results:

```
<path d="M 50 50 L 50 0 
         A 50 50 0 0 1 100 50
         A 50 50 0 0 1 50 100
         A 50 50 0 0 1 0 50
         A 50 50 0 0 1 9.14 21.182 z" stroke="none" fill="#ffb300" />
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhvqo9z2/5/)